# How to invoke python s cript on clicking submit on a web form?

Tags: python, html

my web form looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="formstyle.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form Example</h1>

<form action="checkpoint.py" method="POST">
  <input type="text" size="6" maxlength="20" name="text2" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

On clicking submit, the browser prompts for opening the checkpoint.py file instead of executing it. The file is present in the same folder. Can you please help me with what I am doing wrong here? 
I am completely new to front end and web development.

Comment: You will need to configure your webserver to correctly handle requests to *.py files, e.g. for apache httpd you can use cgi/fastcgi or mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have server running (in my case it is runned in cgi-bin\ directory). Here you have source code:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
webdir = '.'            # where your html files and cgi-bin script directory live
port = 8080               # default http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1
srvraddr = ("", port)
srvrobj = HTTPServer(srvraddr, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
srvrobj.serve_forever()
```

Then you need a script for requests processing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()           # parse form data
print('Content-type: text/html\n')
print('<title>Reply Page</title>')
print(form)
if not 'text2' in form:
    print('<h1>Who are you?</h1>')
else:
    print('<h1>Hello <i>%s</i>!</h1>' % cgi.excape(form['text2'].value))
```

And, of course, html file, which you already have (remember about correct value in "action" form attribute).

Run server (leave it running), open your form (http://localhost**:8080**), and send it - then in your cmd window with running server you should see some info about http request -> that's mean your server is running correctly and getting the requests.

EDIT: this code works on Windows + Python3, but should work also on Linux.